# Identifying a scalar function

Tags: vector-fields, covariance, invariants

We know that a scalar is invariant under rotations. What about a *scalar function*? Should it also be invariant under rotations? Therefore, under rotation $\phi(x,y,z)$ must be equal to $\phi^\prime(x^\prime,y^\prime , z^\prime)$. Where $ (x^\prime,y^\prime , z^\prime)$ is the rotated coordinate system. Does it imply that $$\phi(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$$ is the **only** possible scalar function in three dimension? Can $\phi(x,y,z)=x^2+yz$ be a scalar function?

Answer (score 1):

Good terminology question.

Let's work in some differentiable manifold $M$, our transformation is a smooth map $T: M \to N$. In the case of a rotation $M = N$.

Our $\phi$ is a smooth function $\phi: M \to \mathbb{R}$.

In classical field theory the fact that $\phi$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$ is often expressed by the statement  **"$\phi$ is a scalar field".**

Now the additional demand that $\phi$ is in some sense invariant under $T$ (if $\phi$ is a field it is said that $T$ is a symmetry of the theory) is concretely the requirement:

$$T^*\phi |_{T(p)} = \phi |_p $$
for all $ p \in M$, where $*$ denotes the corresponding [pullback on a smooth function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28differential_geometry%29#Pullback_of_smooth_functions_and_smooth_maps).

Physicist at times call this property **"$\phi$ transforms like a scalar under $T$".**

So to answer your last question:

The smooth map $\phi: (x, y, z) \mapsto x^2 + yz$:

- is a scalar valued function
- does not transform like a scalar under rotations.

Comment: I question this a bit. Of course you are technically correct, but I don't think physicists call scalar fields "scalar" when they are invariant under maps.  Rather this means that when you have for example a $\phi(x^1,...,x^n)$ field, then if you have some coordinate change expressible as $x^i=x^i(y^1,...y^n)$ then if you plug this directly into the field, it won't change, whereas a tensor field expressed in components would have their components changed in the usual manner.

Comment: Contrast this with a so-called scalar density, which is also a scalar-valued field, but picks up the pullback's determinant as a factor, that is something that is scalar valued, but "does not transform as a scalar".

Comment: Here we have a scalar field - maps to $\mathbb{R}$ don't pick up factors under pullbacks, e.g. see the wiki article linked above.

Comment: Regarding the scalar density - if you and I are thinking about the same thing I think the extra factor comes from transformation of the volume element under the same integral

Answer (score 0):

As usual when dealing with transformations one has to be careful whether they are active or passive. If I understand your question you are implying a passive transformation, which is a mere change of coordinates. In this case all you are doing is changing the way you assign a scalar value to a "vector" of coordinates. Therefore $\phi(\mathbf x) = (\phi\circ\xi)(\mathbf x')$, where $\xi$ is the change of coordinates, i.e. $\mathbf x = \xi(\mathbf x')$. You can now set $\phi' = \phi\circ\xi$ to get the covariance for scalar fields
$$\phi(\mathbf x) = \phi'(\mathbf x').$$

To see how this relates to the more general case of tensor fields, where you have the Jacobian of the transformation changing components of tensors, consider that a pseudoscalar (like any tensor density of a certain weight) would transform with a certain power of the determinant of the Jacobian, 1 in this case, hence

$$\phi'(\mathbf x') = \det(D\xi)\phi(\mathbf x).$$

In the active picture you are actually taking the value of the scalar function from a point $p$ to a point $q$ of the manifold and requiring that $\phi(p) = \phi(q)$. This usually happens if $\phi$ has some sort of symmetry, like a spherical potential is invariant under rotation so that you can *transport* the scalar field along the flow of the transformation (this is well defined in the language of Lie derivatives along vector fields and indeed linked to the notion of symmetries).